# call a js function from links in pdf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

We use iframe to show pdf in our `angular` webapp. These pdfs have `href` links inside them that actually are calls to javascript function.

It looks like below.

```
href="javascript:openMyLink('stringOfInformation')"
```

function `openMyLink` is supposed to be present in my webapp and it will use passed `stringOfInformation` to make further REST calls.

The problem is I'm not able to figure out where and how do I write this function. This function may be of global space but it should also be able to access my 
angular services inorder to make REST calls.

I tried writing it inside my controller and even inside a separate file but it is not getting invoked.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't do this. Run javascript in a PDF file? It will be so problematic in security term..

Comment: it impossible! but, you can direct user from pdf to some page and in that page do what you want to do.

Comment: Or try to convert the pdf to html (if it's not complicated).

Comment: @MoshFeu, we had similar functionality in one of our legacy application and a simple global function had helped us earlier.

Comment: So, can't you look what you did there? If you have the answer, please let me know.. Thanks.

Comment: Executing JavaScript within a PDF is certainly possible, Acrobat definitely allows this and prompts the user before allowing the execution to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat does support its own flavor of JavaScript (see the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website).

When there is some JavaScript within the PDF, it has to be Acrobat JavaScript, and follow the according document object model.

The issue is more that in order to make use of that, your users will need a PDF viewer which is smart enough to deal with Acrobat JavaScript (and that number is quite small for Windows/macOS, and very small for iOS/Android, and it is null for the PDF viewers integrated in the web browsers.

Now, if it is a simple link, you won't even need Acrobat JavaScript. Instead of that specify the link within the PDF, using the Link tool. This may be understood by even a bit a bigger range of PDF viewers.